# Check if multiple variables have the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of three variables x, y, z and I want to check if they **all share the same value**. In my case, the value will either be 1 or 0, but I only need to know if they are all the same. Currently I'm using

```
if 1 == x and  1 == y and 1 == z: 
    sameness = True
```

Looking for the answer I've found:

```
if 1 in {x, y, z}:
```

However, this operates as

```
if 1 == x or  1 == y or 1 == z: 
    atleastOneMatch = True
```

Is it possible to check if 1 is in each: x, y, and z?
Better yet, is there a more concise way of checking simply if x, y, and z are the same value?

(If it matters, I use Python 3.)

Comment: One note of caution about these techniques; by trying to make your code more succinct, you are losing the ability to short-circuit the expression. This maybe not have an impact with simple variables but if you were using function calls it might be important.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you have an arbitrary sequence, use the [`all()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
values = [x, y, z]  # can contain any number of values
if all(v == 1 for v in values):
```

otherwise, just use `==` on *all three variables*:

```
if x == y == z == 1:
```

If you only needed to know if they are all the same value (regardless of what value that is), use:

```
if all(v == values[0] for v in values):
```

or

```
if x == y == z:
```

Comment: For the third one, we can also use this: values[1:] == values[:-1]

Comment: @DeSanta: but that creates two new lists.

Comment: Wow. I dint know that. Can you please explain how?

Comment: @DeSanta: slicing a list returns a new list object. `values[1:]` creates a new list object with the references for indices 1 and up copied over. Same for the `values[:-1]`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

To check if they are all the same (either 1 or 2):

```
sameness = (x == y == z)
```

The parentheses are optional, but I find it improves readability

Answer (score 3):

> In my case, the value will either by 1 or 2, **but I only need to know if they are all the same**

> Is it possible to check if 1 is in each: x, y, and z?
>   **Better yet, is there a more concise way of checking simply if x, y, and z are the same value?**

Sure:

```
x == y == z
```

which is equivalent to

```
(x == y) and (y == z)
```

If you have an arbitrary (nonzero) number of values to compare:

```
all(values[0] == v for v in values[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
x == y == z == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something similar to what you have:

```
sameness = (len({x, y, z}) == 1)
```

This allows for any number of variables.  For example:

```
variables = {x, y, z, a, b, ...}
sameness = (len(variables) == 1)
```

**Note:** Creating a set means that each variable needs to be hashed and the hashed values need to be stored, but `all()` with a generator expression is short-circuiting and keeps track of only two values at a time.  Therefore, besides its readability, the generator expression is more efficient.

Comment: Neat use of `set` behaviour, but kinda obscures the intention, don't you think?

Comment: @das-g: Fortunately, the variable name makes the intention clear. Once the intention is clear, it is easy to see how the code works.

Comment: Creating a set is not without cost; each value has to be hashed (in addition to the equality tests), plus the memory allocation for the set object itself. `all()` with a generator expression or a chain of `==` *short circuit*, so not all values need to be tested if at least one value is not equal to the others.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes.  I have added a note to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
sameness = all(e == 1 for e in [x, y, z])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[x,y,z].count(1)
```

will count how many variables have 1 as value

Answer (score 1):

**Below all() and any() functions in python can server the purpose.**

**all() act as "AND"**:  if all the values in any ittertable object is equal to given condition value, then Return True else return False.

**Examples**

```
assert all(b == True for b in [True,True,True,True]) == True
assert all(b == True for b in [False,True,True,True]) == False
```

**any() act as "OR"**:  if any one  value in any ittertable object is equal to given condition value, then Return True else return False.

**Examples**

```
assert any(b == True for b in [False,False,False,True]) == True
assert any(b == True for b in [False,False,False,False]) == False
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple more interesting ways to solve this, in a more general fashion (because why not?)

```py
def method_one(*args: int) -> bool:
    return max(args) == min(args)

def method_two(*args: int) -> bool:
    return sum(args) in (len(args), 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you had more variables, this way might be most concise:

```
{x} == {y, z}
```

(Not as fast as `x == y == z`, but the question asked for concise, not for fast.)

Comment: What's wrong with it?