# How to check if 2 lists with the same length have the same element in the same position but only for one specific element

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that can check two lists and return `True` if both lists have a specific element in the same position.

For example, if a user wanted to check if the number 1 is in the same position in `list1` and `list2`, they could input 1 and the program would check both lists if 1 is in the same position in both lists.

I tried:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] == list2[i]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The problem with this code is it goes for all numbers and not just one in specific.

Comment: Did you try adding one more condition: `list1[i] == 1`?

Comment: This question is essentially answered here: [Python - Check if multiple variables have the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376516/python-check-if-multiple-variables-have-the-same-value)

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a simple solution:

```
list1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
list2 = [5, 4, 3, 1, 10]

def check_item(item, l1, l2):
    # iterate trough the items of l1, l2 simultaneously
    for i1, i2 in zip(l1, l2):
        # check whether the item of list1 is the same as the one in l2 and if they are the same as the targeted item. If so return True
        if i1 == i2 == item:
            return True
    # else return False
    return False

print(check_item(5, list1, list2))
print(check_item(1, list1, list2))
```

You could also one-line it if you'd like:

```
list1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
list2 = [5, 4, 3, 1, 10]

def check_item(item, l1, l2):
    return any(item == i1 == i2 for i1, i2 in zip(l1, l2))


print(check_item(5, list1, list2))
print(check_item(1, list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use zip and the any function like this:

```
x = 1
list1 = [3,2,1,5,4]
list2 = [5,6,1,7,8]
list3 = [1,3,4,5,6]
list4 = [9,8,7,6,5]
list5 = [9,1,1,6,5]

print(any(a==b==x for a,b in zip(list1,list2))) # True
print(any(a==b==x for a,b in zip(list1,list3))) # False
print(any(a==b==x for a,b in zip(list1,list4))) # False
print(any(a==b==x for a,b in zip(list1,list5))) # True
```